# Swap .byte Data using MIPS (QTSPIM)

Tags: mips, mips32, qtspim

I have a .byte data let's say

```
num1: .byte 0x5a
```

I want num1 to be `0xa5` using rotate and shift operations.

I'm new to MIPS. 
Pls Help. Thank You

Comment: MIPS doesn't have any rotate instructions. But it does have AND, OR, left shift, and right shift, which is all you need for this. Consult a MIPS instruction set reference.

Comment: @Michael it has ror rol

Comment: There's no `ror` in the MIPS instruction set. Perhaps the assembler you're using supports it as a pseudo-instruction that gets translated into multiple actual MIPS instructions. There's no need for `ror` for this task though, unless you've got a `ror` instruction that operates on a single byte rather on an entire register.

Comment: @Michael can you help me ?

Comment: @Michael there are rotate instructions since MIPS32/64 Release 2 http://cdn2.imgtec.com/documentation/MIPS_Architecture_MIPS64_InstructionSet_%20AFP_P_MD00087_06.05.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0xfa got converted to 0xaf

```
.data
data1: .byte 0xfa

.text
.globl main
.ent main
 main:

lbu $t0, data1
ror $t1,$t0,4

sll $t2,$t1,4

ror $t6,$t2,4
srl $t3,$t1,4
ror $t4,$t3,20
add $t5,$t4,$t6
li $v0,10
syscall
.end main
```